# MySQL, fetchone and LIMIT

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, query-performance

Here is a sample of python code:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 17"
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

In this example, the query is meant to return at most a single row; but sometimes I want to fetch a single row from a multiple-row result with the same code, for instance:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'foo%'"
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

In term of performance, is it better to explicitly write `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Yes, since you need only 1 why fetch more?

Comment: @ juergen d - LIMIT works after SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the LIMIT clause is executed after the SELECT on the Result set. if you have much rows with the id = 17 , you must transfer a little bit more from the server to the client if you do not use LIMIT.

Comment: _Not true_; or at least not always true.  In the second example, and assuming `INDEX(name)`, exactly 1 probe of the table will happen; it will get _one_ foo row (or find none there).  If there is a `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY`, the `SELECT` will _probably_ have to gather the entire result set before applying the `LIMIT`.

Comment: where is the group / order in the question ?

Comment: Since there is not a `GROUP`/`ORDER`, a `LIMIT` _will_ short-circuit the `SELECT`.  (There may be other exceptions.)  Your answer, as I read it, says that `LIMIT` never short-circuits the `SELECT`.

Comment: Yes, MariaDB has that nice `ROWS EXAMINED` feature, but there are a number of caveats.  It _could_ be used in either of the queries in the question.  But it does not see to add anything over `LIMIT`.